# What's the default frequency of tf.Broadcaster?Is it 60HZ?

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can it be changed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261358/what%27s-the-default-frequency-of-tf.broadcaster?is-it-60hz?/) by [little_bob](https://answers.ros.org/users/30063/little_bob/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2017-05-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're following the linked tutorial. You'll note that sendTransform is called inside every callback. So the transforms will be sent with the frequency at which the `handle_turtle_pose` callback is invoked. Thus you will want to look upstream and see how often that is being published.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [little_bob](https://answers.ros.org/users/30063/little_bob/) on 2017-05-09**:
thanks you very much

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you be a little more specific? Are you talking about `tf` or `tf2`? C++ or Python interface? Or the command line tool? In any case there isn't really a default publishing frequency. Static transforms use a latched topic (in `tf2`, at least) and for normal transforms the publish frequency is controlled by how often you actually send a transform. I suggest you read through the [tf2 tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials), they are quite informative. The `static_transform_publisher` of the (deprecated) `tf` package does allow you to [specify a publishing frequency](http://wiki.ros.org/tf#static_transform_publisher), but `tf2` is the recommended package.

Hope that helps

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2017-05-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [little_bob](https://answers.ros.org/users/30063/little_bob/) on 2017-05-09**:
tf Python.Thanks I'll have a try.But when I receive transforms,I use `rospy.Rate(10).sleep()`, I think the frequency should be 10hz.But when I `rosrun tf view_frammes`, It shows 'turtle2_broadcaster' and 'turtle1_broadcaster''s frequency shows nearly 60HZ.

**Comment by [little_bob](https://answers.ros.org/users/30063/little_bob/) on 2017-05-09**:
I do all these according to this [broadcaster](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20broadcaster%20%28Python%29) This method `tf.TransformBroadcaster().sendTransform()` seems not assigned a default_frequency

**Comment by [little_bob](https://answers.ros.org/users/30063/little_bob/) on 2017-05-09**:
[listener](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28Python%29)

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-05-09**:
Please edit your question to add these details and possibly a screen shot or copy and paste of your console output that you're seeing.